# How to set actual headers on SignalR connection?

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, signalr, signalr.client

Is there a way to set actual headers on the SignalR connection? I know that I can set query string parameters but that's not safe enough for my use case.

```
var conn = ($ as any).hubConnection();
conn.url = URL;
conn.qs = {
    "token": SECRET_KEY
};
conn.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by setting a jQuery Ajax prefilter but it's a little hacky. Hopefully someone knows of a way to do it through the actual SignalR framework.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (request) {
    request.headers = request.headers || {};
    request.headers["token"] = SECRET_KEY;
});
```